# No current context

Tags: java, netbeans, boolean

I used a debugger in NetBeans and made a watch for a certain boolean variable. At a breakpoint it said that that variable had "No current context (stack frame) <" I'm just wondering what that exactly means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer : The debugger simply tells you that it can't evaluate your variable because your boolean variable is not in the memory at your breakpoint.

Regards.

Comment: Also, quit debugging and you'll get a more significant error message (a compile-time type error, in my case). I had forgotten that I was still in debug mode when I saw this.